# R equivalent of Python's hashlib.sha256 function

Tags: python, r, digest, hashlib

I'm trying to replicate the output of the following Python code in R:

```
import hashlib

x = hashlib.sha256()
x.update("asdf".encode("utf8"))
print(x.digest())
# b'\xf0\xe4\xc2\xf7lX\x91n\xc2X\xf2F\x85\x1b\xea\t\x1d\x14\xd4$z/\xc3\xe1\x86\x94F\x1b\x18\x16\xe1;'
```

This is my R code:

```
library(digest)
digest("asdf", algo="sha256", serialize=FALSE)
# "f0e4c2f76c58916ec258f246851bea091d14d4247a2fc3e18694461b1816e13b"
```

I'm able to get this same output in python by using `x.hexdigest()` instead of `x.digest()`. How do I get the output of `x.digest()` in my R code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Python output is the raw bytes of the digest. The R [digest](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/digest/versions/0.6.12/topics/digest) function also supports this with the `raw` argument.

```
digest("asdf", algo="sha256", serialize=FALSE, raw=TRUE)
```

Comment: I should've mentioned that I tried this already. This is the output I get: `f0 e4 c2 f7 6c 58 91 6e c2 58 f2 46 85 1b ea 09 1d 14 d4 24 7a 2f c3 e1 86 94 46 1b 18 16 e1 3b`

Comment: The difference is how R and Python print byte strings -- they represent the same code.